RedShift: Utilizing a field value from one subquery as a field name in an overall query to flatten the data
I am utilizing Amazon Redshift which is based on postgres. I have a table called Engagements which has various data about an Engagement. I have another table which has engagement dates with multiple dates for a single engagement. I'd like to query it so that in a single query I can get all the data for an engagement.
Let's say table Engagements is as follows:



engagementid
title
description




1
Widgets
Widget engagement for Q1


2
Wombats
Wombat engagement for Q1


3
Strawberries
Strawberry engagement for Q3



And the table for engagement_dates is at follows:



engagementid
date_name
date




1
start
2024-01-01


1
launch
2024-03-03


1
end
2024-03-05


2
start
2024-01-05


2
end
2024-03-12


3
cookie
2024-01-01


3
flower
2024-03-03


3
x
2024-03-05



I'd like to be able to query it so that I get data something like the following without the query being hard-coded to specific values of date name.



engagementid
title
description
start_date
launch_date
end_date
cookie_date
flower_date
x_date




1
Widgets
Widget engagement for Q1
2024-01-01
2024-03-03
2024-03-05





2
Wombats
Wombat engagement for Q1
2024-01-05

2024-03-12





3
Strawberries
Strawberry engagement for Q3



2024-01-01
2024-03-03
2024-03-05



Is this possible to do, or do I have to hard-code the values for date_name to pull them out? That solution is a bit ugly with all the CASE statements.

This would be a query with dynamic SQL which suggest a stored procedure to me - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html
A stored procedure that queries the columns needed. Then this SP can execute this dynamic SQL which can just be a PIVOT query.  This approach using a stored procedure is useful in some flows buy is cumbersome for interactive use.
If you are willing to have all the dates in one column as an ordered list - like 'start_date: 2024-01-01, launch_date: 2024-03-03 ...' - then this is a listagg().
You may want to consider changing your date columns in the engagement_dates table to a super data type list as this will afford more flexibility is parsing and using this variable list of dates.
